# Methods to do Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I know this integral can be done using complex analysis. Are there some slick solutions using standard calc methods?

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}dx$

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions?

Comment: @MarkBennet, We were typing the same comment at the same time, but you were a second faster.

Comment: Maybe rewriting the numerator as $\frac18(x^2+9-x^2-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial fractions:

$$\frac1{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}  = \frac18 \left [\frac1{x^2+1} -\frac1{x^2+9}\right ]$$

Answer (score 0):

You could do a partial fraction decomposition to obtain

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)} = \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1} - \frac{1}{x^2+9}\right)$$

Each of the resulting integrals can be evaluated using a substitution
$x = \tan(\theta)$ and $x = 3\tan(\theta)$ respectively. (Alternatively,
the derivative of $\tan^{-1}$ is $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$).